# Why fixed header for grid view didn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gone through this example for fixed header of grid view. When i did as per that using table that works fine, but when i have `gridview` in place of `table` this didn't work can any one help me

http://www.tablefixedheader.com/demonstration/

This is my source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css"
        id="link" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="highlighter/codehighlighter.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="highlighter/javascript.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.fixheadertable.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="font-family: Verdana,Arial,Geneva,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">


        <asp:GridView ID="fixmyheader" CssClass="fixmyheader" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

        <script type="text/javascript">            // <![CDATA[
            $('#fixmyheader').fixheadertable({ height: '200', minWidth: 800,  zebra: true });
            // ]]&gt;</script>
    </div>
```

I tried this too but i am unable to achieve i required with `gridview`

http://fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTML source of your page. Althoguh you've given the GridView an ID of fixMyHeader, on the client, it might actually be different, as ASP.Net will generate unique id's for controls on the page based on the id you'ev assigned.

You could try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#<%=fixmyheader.ClientID%>').fixheadertable({ height: '200', minWidth: 800,  zebra: true });
</script>
```

for example.

Does it work if you try it on a normal table on the same page (just to check you have all of the javascript dependencies?)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a case of cut and past problem?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">            // <![CDATA[
        $('#fixmyheader').fixheadertable({ height: '200', minWidth: 800,  zebra: true });
        // ]]&gt;</script>
```

Shouldnt it be?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        $('#fixmyheader').fixheadertable({ height: '200', minWidth: 800,  zebra: true });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

That in combination with dash's fix:

```
<%=fixmyheader.ClientID%>
```

would hopefully fix the problem. :)